# Alamofire request is send twice

Tags: swift

I’m alamofire request, and I found the request is sent twice. Is it an alamofire bug?

I tried to put a breakpoint, but it's not called twice and there is no button call this function twice or trigging twice.

Here is my code

```
    ARSLineProgress.show()
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://laghmat.kbmediawebites.com/api/rest/account") else {return}
    let headers = ["X-Oc-Merchant-Id": MerchantId, "X-Oc-Session": K_Defaults.string(forKey: "sessionID"),"ACCEPT":"application/json"]
    let params = [
        "firstname": firstName,
        "lastname": lastName,
        "email": email,
        "telephone": phone
    ] as! [String : String]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers as! HTTPHeaders).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(GeneralResponse.self, from: data)
                if value.success == 1 {
                    ARSLineProgress.showSuccess()
                    var user = GlobalHelpers.getUser()
                    user?.firstname = firstName
                    user?.lastname = lastName
                    user?.telephone = phone
                    user?.email = email
                    GlobalHelpers.setUser(user)
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    ARSLineProgress.showFail()
                    self.alert(msg: LanguageManger.localize(word: "serverError"))
                }
            } catch let error {
                ARSLineProgress.showFail()
                self.alert(msg: LanguageManger.localize(word: "serverError"))
                print(error)
            }

            break
        case .failure(let error):
            ARSLineProgress.showFail()
            self.alert(msg: LanguageManger.localize(word: "serverError"))
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your user can 'accidentally' press the button twice? (If you have a button?)

Comment: i've checked that too.

Comment: put a breakpoint on request line, make sure it only executes once.

Comment: I bet something along the lines of myself or @GustavoVollbrecht's comment has something to do with it; however, we are unable to further debug because we are only able to see the code being executed, not how you are actually calling it. Something that might help us would be to post the various places that you call this -- like a button click, page swipe, etc, etc. Then we could potentially scope it down towards "hey, you might be pressing the button twice" :)

Comment: I've already tried all these steps, but it is not fixed.
I updated my code.

Comment: When you say “I found the request is sent twice,” how did you deduce that? If you’re watching web server activity and/or watching via something like Charles/WireShark, it’s worth noting that in some special situations, you can see multiple requests going back and forth behind the scenes (e.g. if the web service has some authentication challenge, etc.). But we’d need more information about how you determined that multiple requests were getting sent and you need to confirm that this routine, itself, isn’t getting called multiple times (a logging statement or breakpoint) for some other reason.

Comment: Unrelated, you don’t need `break` statements in Swift `switch` statements.

Answer (score 0):

well I recommend you that lock all the buttons in the view, when the request is made.

```
for viewW in view.subviews
{
   if let buttonV = viewW as? UIButton
   {
      buttonV.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
   }
}
```

obviously, you have to lock at the beginning and unlock at the end.

if this isn't works, put a breakpoint in this line

```
switch response.result {
```

the first time, you will see that you don't have a status code, because the server not yet responding, then press next step, and you will see a status code, because the server already responds to you.

that doesn't mean the request is made twice, I think that this happen because the handshake is happening.